# Did drawbacks of egalitarianism or mismanagement cause the rural famine in the Great Leap Forward?

Tags: china, mao-zedong, famine

In China "[大锅饭](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%A4%A7%E9%94%85%E9%A5%AD/359289?fr=aladdin)" (communal dining in English) implies egalitarianism and slack of people, which is the premise of the statement that the famine is partly due to the laziness of the people. As we can see from the previous link (from
China's Baidupedia):

> 大锅饭（mess together）是对分配方面存在的平均主义现象的一种形象比喻，大锅饭的概念，最早可追溯到1958年人民公社的出现，同样是与大跃进加速工业积累密切相关的。弊端: 压抑人们的积极性

But I notice that the following two pieces of evidence conflict with that premise.

First, I read the following statement from Wikipedia:

> The communes exercised management and control of all rural resources such as labor and land. Because of governmental mismanagement of resources and bad weather from 1958 to 1960 the Great Chinese Famine spread over the countryside, with much food being exported to urban areas.

I thought most researchers would attribute the famine to mismanagement rather than the people's laziness.

Second, people's workload was increased in that period as we can see in [China Under Mao: A Revolution Derailed by Andrew G. Walder](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0674975499):

> This work was largely uncompensated and was in no way voluntary. If you refused to work, you had no right to eat in the collective mess hall, the only source of food. ... Farmers were expected to obey strict rules of discipline: obey the leader and follow orders; work actively; do not arrive late or depart early; ... Farmers were required to work at least twenty-eight days each month. ... Prior to the great Leap, labor on collective farms had a rhythm that was determined by the seasons. Planting and harvesting were the busiest periods, and winter was slack time. The Great Leap obliterated this rhythm with constant and seemingly ceaseless demands for hard labor, not only in the fields but also on massive irrigation projects, road building, and terracing of hillsides.

I cannot imagine how would there be any slackers under the pressure of more and more inflated targets.

I thought the provenance of the meaning of "大锅饭" in Baidupedia was manipulated in order to cover the mismanagement problem caused by the mutual deception and self-deception. Am I right？

Comment: I have no comment on the original text but to define this as an issue of egalitarianism's failings (in English) makes no sense to me.

Comment: Software Enginner Hat on here: Any time a large system fails, and the designers blame great masses of common people for not being good or smart or virtuous enough to properly operate the system, that's a pile of fresh grade A steaming nonsense. At best, they should have known what their own people were like, and created a system that would work better with those people. But realistically, people are the same world-wide, and if your system doesn't work with real people, its a crappy system. That's **your** fault, not theirs.

Comment: not to toot my own horn, but this answer by me on another question may be helpful: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/62848/had-the-chinese-leadership-considered-the-famine-in-soviet-union-in-1930s-before/62864#62864

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Incompetency and deliberate malice

First of all, we should note that in years immediately after the end of civil war in 1949, China was still largely backward agricultural society. Apparently, only 3% of the population [lived in urban settlements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urbanization_in_China) . Agriculture was based on small households with relatively primitive and obsolete farming techniques. Couple these with devastation caused by war and Japanese occupation, and it is not a surprise that food was not exactly plentiful even in these first years of People's Republic. However, situation was nowhere near as dire as it will become in few years latter due to communist meddling.

Stated goal of CCP was modernization of the country, which included industrialization and increased agricultural production. On the surface there is nothing wrong with that, but the manner it was done was artificial, plain stupid and even malicious. For example, traditional economic theories postulate that in country such as China industry should first follow needs of the agriculture, i.e. industry should primarily focus on producing goods that would increase agricultural output. Such increased output would then be invested towards infrastructure, education and further industrialization.

Note that Chinese communist were not satisfied with such "capitalist" theories. They wanted everything and now - rapid industrialization, modern agriculture, strong military and from beginning of [Khrushchev Thaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khrushchev_Thaw) they strived to reduce dependence on USSR due to ideological divergence and latter Sino-Soviet split. In theory, main difference between [Maoism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maoism) and more mainstream Marxism (Stalinism and Leninism) is in a problem of revolutionary class. Marxism states that working class (proletariat) is a main drive for change. Maoism instead relied on poor peasants, since China didn't have meaningful number of traditional industrial workers. However, in practice, Chinese communists wanted to transform and remold these enormous masses of peasantry into modern socialist (and latter communist) society, even if that meant millions of them would die. Attitude of Chinese communists towards its own population were best described by this quote of Mao Zedong

> “I’m not afraid of nuclear war. There are 2.7 billion people in the world; it doesn’t matter if some are killed. China has a population of 600 million; even if half of them are killed, there are still 300 million people left.”

This is obviously about nuclear war, but it shows mindset pretty accurately.

With such mindset, CCP proceeded with destructive policies. It should be noted that collectivization in China begun somewhat before of Great Leap Forward, i.e. already from [1950](https://chineseposters.net/themes/land-reform) some land reforms were enacted. However from 1958 collectivization became massive and compulsory, similar to previous Soviet collectivization and similarly disruptive. Agricultural output dropped, but at the same time due to attempts of industrialization more food was requisitioned to feed growing army of industrial workers and other city dwellers. To add to the burden, villagers were often forcibly put to work on projects like digging canals for irrigation. Communist were prepared to sacrifice thousands in such projects as this Mao quote witnesses :

> Wu Zhipu claims he can move 30 billion cubic metres; I think 30,000 people will die. Zeng Xisheng has said that he will move 20 billion cubic metres, and I think that 20,000 people will die. Weiqing only promises 600 million cubic metres, maybe nobody will die.

Overall, collectivization, forced work, employment of new and supposedly modern agricultural techniques (in fact done with little bio-technological knowledge) created [Great Chinese Famine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Chinese_Famine) of 1958-1962. Countryside was devastated and millions died. Mao was forced to back down a bit, although he arranged comeback with [Cultural Revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_Revolution). It should be noted that this first wave of industrialization was mostly a failure - due to the lack of even basic industrial knowledge failed projects like [backyard furnaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backyard_furnace) were created. Overall, **Mao Zedong and his accomplices cost China at least 30 years of development and likely 100 million deaths**.

Comment: As a sub-category of malice, one should note that if a certain amount of food is produced, reducing the number of people among it whom it is distributed will increase the amount per recipient.  If one ignores the people who aren't allowed any food, and if such starvation does not adversely affect food production, restricting distribution may make things look better "on paper".

Comment: *"Mao Zedong and his accomplices cost China at least 30 years of development and likely 100 million deaths."* - compared to what counterfactual? Compared to the hypothetical possibility of more competent management, or compared to the old regime (whose economic regressiveness cost a comparable number of deaths to famine in the first half of the 20thC alone)?

Comment: @supercat Problem is that actual production of food was significantly reduced. So, it was not the question of starving "useless people". May peasants who were actually very useful, i.e. they could work and produced food before, now starved to death because they were forced to produce low quality pig iron (among other things) . It was not rational malice, it was malice mixed with stupidity.

Comment: @Steve Considering the fact that Mao actually decreased production, and arguably reforms enacted by  Deng Xiaoping in 1980s could have been implemented from the beginning, you get the picture. Note that  Xiaoping was also a communist, and far from ideal. Yet, considering vast potential of China, even his mildly competent management yielded significant progress. You could also compare with Japan and South Korea. Bot countries had their own problems, yet they developed much faster and less deadly then China.

Comment: @rs.29, my purpose is not to argue about the overall competence of Mao, but to clarify on what basis he is being accused of holding development back for "at least 30 years". The comparison to Japan and South Korea is hardly pertinent - Japan was already a first-world country, and South Korea has received massive economic and military subsidy from the Western world, for geopolitical reasons. The history of major 'communist' revolutions in agrarian economies is not that they hold development back, but that industrial development surges compared to unsubsidised capitalist regimes.

Comment: @Steve Well, actually Japan was bombed and occupied country,  South Korea was Japanese colony and after that suffered war. They actually didn't get much free help. And history of communist revolutions in agrarian economies as a pattern shows gross mismanagement and devastation. On the other hand, non-communist countries did industrialize and much more efficiently . In capitalist world there is no such thing as free help,  and no country ever succeed because of some mythical aid.

Comment: @rs.29, I'm afraid that is codswallop. Japan itself was a beneficiary of American largesse under an analogy of the Marshall Plan. It's a malicious falsehood to say there is no free help in the capitalist world, or that aid was mythical. I agree that communist revolutions show gross mismanagement in the early stages - Mao's backyard furnaces as a prime example - but that is attributable to management inexperience which rapidly eases, which you do not appear to acknowledge.

Comment: @Steve They were not beneficiary, US invested in them. They didn't get anything for free. In fact they are still paying political price of this. There is nothing free in capitalist world (or even non-capitalists world) . As for Mao and his ilk, they were both incompetent and malicious. Incompetent because they didn't know even basic things. Malicious because they killed those that did know, and were ready to pay for their incompetence with other people's lives intentionally, and never acknowledged their mistakes.

Comment: @rs.29, and investment causes rapid development. It's completely immaterial what the long-term price is perceived to be - the point is to address the claim that these nations "developed much faster". I'd accept that Mao knew little about basic things, but that's because they were revolutionaries who had to purge the existing management and had no experience themselves - that changed within 25 years. As for not acknowledging mistakes, they certainly learned from them.

Comment: @Steve Good investment makes profit, but failed investment causes hardship. CCP made failed investment in backyard furnaces that cost not only capital but also human lives. And there is no proof that Mao ever learned from his mistakes - he continued with Cultural Revolution that did even more damage. Others like Xiaoping certainly did learn and knew better, but could not do much while Mao was alive and even some years after his death.

Comment: @rs.29, I thought we were talking about the Chinese regime collectively, rather than specific people. I think Mao did acknowledge that backyard furnaces were a mistake - I don't see how he could have sustained any other opinion - but he was primarily a revolutionary, and he delivered on that. He was not an engineer or metallurgist.

Comment: @Steve Mao and his cronies ruled practically until his death, and even some time after that. During that time almost every move he made was damaging to Chinese economy. Yeah, he probably learned that backyard furnaces do not work, but that didn't stop him from sending university professors and other highly skilled specialists to work as farmhands during Cultural Revolution. He was a revolutionary until 1949, but after that until 1976 he was a cancerous tissue that threatened to destroy China.

Comment: @rs.29, it can't be said that every move he made was damaging to the economy, otherwise there would be no explanation for the surging levels of civil and industrial development. You mention specialists working as farmhands, but again basic education levels also surged in the countryside. I'm not sure you're attempting to give a balanced view on this subject, rather than a puff piece against revolutions or 'communism'.

Comment: @Steve You know, if left alone, economy tends to develop on its own ;) Chinese were very successful businessmen all around the globe except in China. Reason - CCP stifled them. There is no beating around the bush - communism creates poverty, devastation and death. Especially Maoism.  You don't need to starve some kids to death in order to educate other.  You do not need to kill thousands in order to erect dams. Facts of life.

Comment: @rs.29, if it were true that the economy just spontaneously develops on its own, there would be no uneven development of the world. The reality is that industrialisation requires changes in social relations, and very often parasitic elites must be cleared out. You do often need to kill thousands, not to build the dam itself, but to establish the prior right to direct that a dam be built and overrule any objections. The history of the roads and railways was also a battle against recalcitrant landowners and vested interests, for example.

Comment: @Steve Well, economy did spontaneously developed on its own :D Until mid 19th century government interventions were rare and weak. Also development of economy depends on social, historical, geographical, genetic ... factors . There is nothing even or equal in nature, still things get done. Chinese communists did kill a lot of people to get the land, but they also killed lot of people during construction which was completely unnecessary.

Comment: @rs.29, again you're falling back into statements of pure codswallop. Railways required special legislation just to build them. The American railways were extensively funded by the state.

Comment: @Steve Nope. In US state helped by expropriating land. But costs were paid by railway companies. See for example : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albany_and_Schenectady_Railroad

Comment: @rs.29, it's immaterial that private firms laid the railroads, or private investment was raised in part. The point I made was that the *rights to do so* had to be established, and the state was very much involved from the outset, including on financing. I don't see why you're continuing down this foolishly argued road.

Comment: @Steve There is a huge difference between eminent domain, and state being largest and even sole investor in every project in the land. Latter is a domain of communism, and as we could see from various examples, far from being optimal for the economy. Economy of US was not built by US government or state governments, it was built by private citizens. CCP on the other hand effectively destroyed that ability for Chinese citizens, even if they were just poor farmers with few scraps of land.

Comment: @rs.29, you're shifting the goalposts. The contention you made was that the economy will simply develop on its own - presumably without industrially-uninformed revolutionaries like Mao. I contend the contrary, that revolutions are sometimes necessary to establish a ruling class who are willing and able to use state power to force industrialisation against the will of the existing ruling class (for example, backward-minded rentier landowners, or guilds that control existing non-industrialised production). (1/2)

Comment: @Steve Economy in US did develop on this own. There was no need for "forced industrialization" . Instead, in our example people actually wanted railroad to move their products to distant markets (cotton, cattle , grain etc ...) .

Comment: To support this I mention the example of railways, which clearly require a state that is willing and able to drive over landlords, smash down the tariff barriers and toll gates that were once a typical right of landowners, and is capable of either raising the finance directly from taxation or of delivering confidence in a system that raises private investment (i.e. legal rights and enforcement powers). Revolutions clear away ruling classes who, in diverse ways, pose obstacles to such industrial development. They don't always just naturally wither or adapt - often they must be smashed. (2/2)

Comment: @rs.29, the US was a settler colony of Britain, which underwent revolutions of its own to terminate the extraction of economic rents by the British, freeing them to reallocate those economic resources to their own development.

Comment: @Steve I cannot think of any country where ruling class actually opposed building of railroads :) Usually they would benefit the most due to increased trade . They would even benefit if their land was expropriated , because that would be more than generously compensated.

Comment: @Steve Americans simply didn't want "taxation without representation" . I.e. they wanted political power if they were paying taxes. They were not opposed to British style of economy, in fact they continued with pretty much same practices when they gained independence.

Comment: @rs.29, the very fact that their land *is* expropriated, and not simply purchased on the market, confirms my stance and not yours. Compensation was generous, but state intervention was needed to make the transaction compulsory, limit rent-seeking behaviours and fussiness around the transaction, and to terminate traditional rights to levy tariffs at boundaries or to control passage of goods internally (bearing in mind that in the UK there were multiple levels of landlords and complex arrangements of rights, and most land was not simply owned outright by an individual). (1/2)

Comment: As to the Americans, I didn't suggest they were opposed to a British-style (i.e. capitalist) economy. On the contrary, I'm suggesting that as a settler colony, they inherited the broad mentality of the British, who by then were already underway with industrialisation and capitalist expansion (which is precisely why the American settler colony existed). The indigenous peoples did of course have to be steamrollered with violence, and their existing rights and lifestyles extinguished, which is another example of resistance that has to be overcome for economic development. (2/2)

Comment: @Steve You are building a strawman argument. Eminent domain is ancient right of the state, and it has nothing to do with your claim that state builds economy. In fact, I have proven to you that economy (i.e. private capital) influenced decisions of politicians to use eminent domain to build railroads. Completely different than communist system where state became sole (and rather stupid and destructive) investor.

Comment: @Steve Btw, I never said that capitalism is perfect, or even non-violent (since such thing dose not exist in this world) . I just said that communism and socialism in general have been proven to be much worse alternatives.

Comment: @rs.29, what do you mean by an "ancient right of the state"? Monarchs could not in general appropriate tracts of land, or deny established rights, without causing political upset. My original claim was not that "the state builds the economy", but that regressive ruling classes must sometimes be cleared away by force, and that one of the key things revolutions deliver is the facilities and *rights* to engage in economic development. (1/2)

Comment: You assume that China would have just developed anyway, but that fails to appreciate that their society had already been regressing in relative development for centuries, and famine stalked the land under the old regime *even in normal years* with no political upset. (2/2)

Comment: @Steve Eminent domain stems from ancient rights of monarch to do exactly that, i.e. take away possession from their vassals, because by medieval legal theory whole realm belongs to "God anointed one" i.e. monarch.  There was no regressive ruling class in China, especially in 1958. There was essentially mass of rather poor peasants, and they were killed en masse by blood thirsty communists, instead of letting them develop the land.

Comment: @Steve Also, China did have economic development before the Japanese attack and example of Taiwan shows that they would have developed much faster after WW2 had Kuomintang managed to gain (in fact remain in)  power.  Note that Kuomintang was far from perfect, but was much better than communists considering economy and overall care for citizens.

Comment: @rs.29, actually a British King had his head chopped off for attempting to assert divine rights, and he struggled even to raise money taxes, let alone seize land. The Chinese communists did not widely kill the peasantry due to "bloodthirst" so far as I'm aware - this is just baseless rhetoric. And if the Kuomintang were so good, why did they not have the support of the population? Revolutions don't happen out of thin air. And note the Kuomintang themselves were not the established regime.

Comment: @Steve Depends on period. British kings and queens also chopped many heads themselves and seized lands of large number of nobles. Attitude of CCP toward their countryman is clearly seen in quotes in my answer above. Kuomintang was far from perfect and they squandered their opportunities. Also, communists had better propaganda. Had they told peasants that millions of them would starve to death I doubt they would have large support. Btw, same mechanism could be seen in US today - leftists are promising free stuff but will deliver only economic pain.

Comment: @rs.29, the issue doesn't deserve any more discussion. I think I've said enough to establish firstly that the exertion of state power is necessary for economic development, and secondly that for a variety of reasons ruling classes have often neglected, frustrated, or opposed economic development. As for peasants, their allegiance to Mao and his successors appears largely undimmed, and the Chinese economy only ever grows, as do Chinese wages, which is in stark contrast to Western capitalism at the hands of neoliberals who took over in the 70s.

Comment: @Steve No, you have proven nothing because link between eminent domain and sending millions to their deaths is simply ludicrous, and ruling classes in most cases actually encouraged development. Notwithstanding that ruling class in China in 1958 was CCP. As for Chinese peasants they were simply beaten dog that still licked his master's boots. Chinese economy started growing only after Mao's death as indeed they have lost 30 years and unnumbered souls. Finally, even CCP had to admit that "Mao was 70% right and 30% wrong, which in reality means that he was 100% wrong, evil and deviant.

Comment: @rs.29, I wasn't attempting to prove the link you claim. As for "beaten dogs licking boots", I see no reason why we couldn't apply that hypothesis to the capitalist world. You seem to think I'm contending for Mao's economic competence - I'm not. He was an ignorant economic manager, perhaps even a fool in many respects. I'm contending that the revolution he led and secured was his primary positive contribution, and I reject (for the reasons already stated) that China would be in its current situation of economic powerhouse if that revolution had not occurred. (1/2)

Comment: You talk of course of famines, deaths, a cynical disregard for life, and economic stagnation. But the Chinese economy was already characterised by famines, mainly on account of stagnation and underdevelopment. The KMT were infamous for their death count and cynical disregard for life. Mao has been replaced by competent economic management, who learned their lessons, and continue to deliver consistent soaring growth and development for the Chinese people, but without slavish commitment to economic liberalism. In that respect the revolution Mao led has been a long-term success story. (2/2)

Comment: @Steve No matter how bad was KMT (and they were bad) they were vastly superior to CCP. You have Taiwan to prove it. Accept the simple fact that communist revolution was entirely unnecessary and damaging to China. Accept the fact that Taiwan still has better standard of living than mainland China after all these years of abandoning Mao's policies.  Simply saying, Mao left permanent scar to Chinese people, wound he has made will be tough to heal.

Comment: @rs.29, we're retreading old ground without you answering the points I previously made. Taiwan would already have been swallowed by China if it did not fall under the military umbrella of the US - frankly, China could buy the place for cash, let alone conquer the regime militarily. And Taiwan (like other regimes in the Far East) would not have developed without subsidy and preferential terms from the West, the purpose of which is to artificially create the contrast you now invoke, and which only occurs due to the presence of the Chinese regime.

Comment: @Steve We are not talking about military, we are talking about economy. And frankly, people in Taiwan don't want to live in CCP system even today, not to mention during times of Mao. West never gave anything for free, Taiwanese earned what they have and repaid the debts. As a conclusion I could only repeat that Mao and CCP cost China 30 years of development and around 100 millions of lives. In this regard Mao was worse than Stalin, and perhaps even worse than Stalin and Hitler combined.

Comment: @rs.29, of course the West gives something for free, namely the military umbrella which reduces the need for small client states to support a strong military. The same is true of West Germany postwar. Next, my suggestion was not that the loans were always interest free - I'm saying the fact that they were granted at all is itself a benefit. Perhaps Mao cost 30 years of development compared to if the revolution was led by an expert in steel production, but that's just unfortunate - it's not an argument against the revolution itself, since the KMT had no special skills in steel either. (1/2)

Comment: As for the death count, 100m is only what famine, war, flood, and mismanagement, had cost China in the 50 years preceding the revolution (all things which ceased to inflict any toll whatever after the 1960s), and as a percentage of the Chinese population it is relatively modest - in fact the GLF period simply represented an absence of growth in population, rather than an actual reduction. Frankly I find it tiresome to keep hearing about how many hundreds of millions that communism supposedly kills - the Chinese were so fecund that they could lose 100m and still need a one-child policy. (2/2)

Comment: @Steve Not true. Cost of military umbrella is purchase of Western (usually US) military equipment which is not cheap, and in some cases having US bases on your own territory. Loans were not free, and as in case of Germany, they included acceptance of US dollar hegemony. Also, had KMT have won, China would undoubtedly get similar loans. That is one point against CCP, not for them.

Comment: @Steve Official count by PRC is around 20 million dead in WW2 (1937-45) . CCP managed to outdo Japanese in a very short time during peace. And frankly, if you think that China had overabundance of population and therefore they should just simply kill off excess people, then there is nothing more  to discuss with you.